# Can react hooks be used inside JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've recently come across the following code:

```js
    import React, { useContext } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import UserContext from 'UserContext';
    const useUserName = () => {
      const context = useContext(UserContext);
      return context.userName;
    }

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          {useUserName()}
        </div>
      );
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`useUserName` returns user name as a string. It seems instinctively strange and wrong that react hook `useUserName` is used inside JSX that is inside the "render" function. Is this valid usage? I couldn't find any reference which forbids such usage.

Comment: Why does it seem weird? :)

Comment: The `useContext` isn't valid hook usage though. It must be at the top level of the component, i.e. within `App`. And neither is `useUserName`, it's not in a functional component body at all. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level **BTW** the entire functional component body *is* the "render" function ;)

Comment: @DrewReese it is used at the top **level**. the rule says Don't use it inside of structures like Conditions/loops, etc. not  It has to be the first you do in a component. There's nothing conditional, the way OP uses this hook.

Comment: @Thomas "..., or nested functions" But you are quite right, I somehow misread that that is *the* hook function definition, not an invocation outside `App`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems instinctively strange and wrong that react hook useUserName is used inside JSX that is inside the "render" function.

The entire component is nothing but a `render()` function.

> Is this valid usage?

What's the difference between that and

```
function App() {
  const userName = useUserName();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {userName}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is valid and will work.

That said, I would suggest not to do it since someone can wrap this JSX with a conditional rendering and not noticing you are using a hook. Then it will be like calling it inside a condition. lets say someone add a code that is something like that:

```
return (
    isLoading ? <Spinner/> : (
        <div className="App">
            {useUserName()}
        </div>
    )
);
```

And that is forbidden. The [legacy docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) of React explains why properly